# how to increment a message header

Tags: spring-integration, dsl

Is there a way in Spring Integration Java DSL to modify an existing message header?

I am reimplementing a download retry mechanism using SI Java DSL, and want to increment a message header holding the download attempts when a failure occurs, before routing the message based on the number of attempts compared to a limit.

I have the routing working nicely based upon the RouterTests included with SI. With HeaderEnrichers I can easily add a header, but I can't see a way to modify an existing header.

Thanks

```
/**
 * Unit test of {@link RetryRouter}.
 * 
 * Based on {@link RouterTests#testMethodInvokingRouter2()}.
 */
@ContextConfiguration
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@DirtiesContext
public class RetryRouterTests {

    /** Failed download attempts are sent to this channel to be routed by {@link ContextConfiguration#failedDownloadRouting( ) } */
    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("failed")
    private MessageChannel failed;

    /** Retry attempts for failed downloads are sent to this channel by {@link ContextConfiguration#failedDownloadRouting( ) }*/
    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("retry-channel")
    private PollableChannel retryChannel;

    /** Failed download attempts which will not be retried, are sent to this channel by {@link ContextConfiguration#failedDownloadRouting( ) }*/
    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("exhausted-channel")
    private PollableChannel exhaustedChannel;

    /**
     * Unit test of {@link ContextConfiguration#failedDownloadRouting( ) } and {@link RetryRouter}.
     */
    @Test
    public void retryRouting() {

        final int limit = 2;

        for ( int attempt = 0 ; attempt <= limit + 1 ; attempt++ ){

            this.failed.send( failed( attempt, limit) );

            if ( attempt < limit){

                assertEquals( payload( attempt ) , this.retryChannel.receive( ).getPayload( ) );
                assertNull(this.exhaustedChannel.receive( 0 ) );

            }else{

                assertEquals( payload( attempt ) , this.exhaustedChannel.receive( ).getPayload( ) );
                assertNotNull( this.exhaustedChannel.receive( ).getPayload( ) );
            }
        }

    }

    private Message<String> failed( int retry , int limit ) {

        return MessageBuilder
            .withPayload(  payload( retry ) )
            .setHeader("retries", new AtomicInteger( retry ) )
            .setHeader("limit", limit)
            .build();
    }

    private String payload (int retry){
        return "retry attempt "+retry;
    }


    @Configuration
    @EnableIntegration
    public static class ContextConfiguration {

        @Bean
        public MessageChannel loggerChannel() {
            return MessageChannels.direct().get();
        }

        @Bean(name = "retry-channel")
        public MessageChannel retryChannel() {
            return new QueueChannel();
        }

        @Bean(name = "exhausted-channel")
        public MessageChannel exhaustedChannel() {
            return new QueueChannel();
        }


        /**
         * Decides if a failed download attempt can be retried or not, based upon the number of attempts already made 
         * and the limit to the number of attempts that may be made. Logic is in {@link RetryRouter}.
         * <p>
         * The number of download attempts already made is provided as a header {@link #attempts} from the connector doing the download, 
         * and the limit to the number of attempts is another header {@link #retryLimit} which is originally setup as
         * a header by {@link DownloadDispatcher} from retry configuration.
         * <p>
         * Messages for failed download attempts are listened to on channel {@link #failed}. 
         * Retry attempts are routed to {@link #retryChannel()}
         *  
         * @return
         */
        @Bean
        public IntegrationFlow failedDownloadRouting() {

            return IntegrationFlows.from( "failed" )

                .handle( "headers.retries.getAndIncrement()" )
                .handle( logMessage ( "failed" ) )
                .route(new RetryRouter())
                .get();
        }

        /**
         * Decides if a failed download attempt can be retried or not, based upon the number of attempts already made 
         * and the limit to the number of attempts that may be made. 
         * <p>
         */
        private static class RetryRouter {

            @Router
            public String routeByHeader(@Header("retries") AtomicInteger attempts , @Header("limit") Integer limit) {

                if (attempts.intValue() < limit.intValue()){
                    return "retry-channel";
                }
                return "exhausted-channel";
            }

            /** This method is not used but is required by Spring Integration otherwise application context doesn't load because of
             * {@code Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Target object of type 
             * [class org.springframework.integration.dsl.test.routers.RetryRouterTests$RetryRouter] has no eligible methods for handling Messages.}
             * 
             * @throws UnsupportedOperationException if called
             */
            @SuppressWarnings("unused")
            public String routeMessage(Message<?> message) {

                throw new UnsupportedOperationException( "should not be used." );
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 6):

There is a way do what you need without modifications for headers:

```
.enrichHeaders(h -> h.header("downloadRetries", new AtomicInteger()))
```

Then when you need to increment it you should do just this:

```
.handle(m -> m.getHeaders().get("downloadRetries", AtomicInteger.class).getAndIncrement())
```

and this handle as a first one-way first subscriber on the publish-subscriber-channel for the retry service.

**UPDATE**

> is a one-way 'MessageHandler' and it isn't appropriate to configure 'outputChannel'. This is the end of the integration flow.

Thank you for sharing the config on the matter: now I an issue and you misundestanding. The solution must be like this:

```
        return IntegrationFlows.from( "failed" )

            .publishSubscribeChannel(s -> s
                .subscribe(f -> f
                        .handle(m -> m.getHeaders().get("downloadRetries",
                                  AtomicInteger.class).getAndIncrement()))
            .handle( logMessage ( "failed" ) )
            .route(new RetryRouter())
            .get();
    }
```

Where we have a `PublishSubscribeChannel`, the `.subscribe()` in the sub-flow is a first subscriber for the first one, and `.handle( logMessage ( "failed" ) )` in the main flow is a second subscriber. The last one won't be called until the finish of work of the first one subscriber.

See the Spring Integration [Reference Manual](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/latest-ga/reference/html/messaging-channels-section.html#channel-implementations-publishsubscribechannel) and [Java DSL Manual](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-java-dsl/wiki/Spring-Integration-Java-DSL-Reference#subflows) for more info.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am unsure of the significance of the qualifier 'first one-way first subscriber on the publish-subscriber-channel'. I tried it out in my test code, which I have added to the original question, but get an error that I am unable to make any progress with, will add in the next comment.

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Found ambiguous parameter type [class java.lang.String] for method match: [public byte[] ..... java.lang.String java.lang.String.valueOf(long)]
 at org.springframework.util.Assert.isNull(Assert.java:92)
 at org.springframework.integration.util.MessagingMethodInvokerHelper.findHandlerMethodsForTarget(MessagingMethodInvokerHelper.java:497)

Comment: Sorry, that was my mistake: the `.handle()` doesn't support `expression` variant. See an update in my answer. You should provide the `MessageHandler` implementation to get access to the `MessageHeaders`.

Comment: Thanks for your help.  It doesn't run : Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: The 'currentComponent' (org.springframework.integration.dsl.test.routers.RetryRouterTests$ContextConfiguration$1@3b00856b) is a one-way 'MessageHandler' and it isn't appropriate to configure 'outputChannel'. This is the end of the integration flow.

Comment: See an **UPDATE** to my answer.

Answer (score 2):

The following code does work

```
.handle( new GenericHandler<Message<String>>() {

    @Override
    public Object handle( Message<String> payload , Map<String,Object> headers ) {

        ((AtomicInteger)headers.get( "retries" )).getAndIncrement();
        return payload;
    }})
```