# what are JMS equivalents of DirectChannel and QueueChannel in the JAVA DSL?

Tags: java, jms, activemq-classic, spring-integration, dsl

I have developed what I think is a good solution in Spring Boot and Integration, using the Java DSL, with DirectChannel and QueueChannel beans. This is based upon the example code RouterTests#testMethodInvokingRouter2.

Now I want to move it into ActiveMQ. If I import ActiveMQAutoConfiguration I get an instance of ConnectionFactory. But how do I replace the following beans with the JMS equivalents?:

```
@Bean(name = "failed-channel")
public MessageChannel failedChannel() {
    return new DirectChannel();
}

@Bean(name = "retry-channel")
public MessageChannel retryChannel() {
    return new QueueChannel();
}

@Bean(name = "exhausted-channel")
public MessageChannel exhaustedChannel() {
    return new QueueChannel();
}
```

Is there any easy way to do this or am I barking up the wrong tree?

Complete code below

```
@ContextConfiguration
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@DirtiesContext
public class RetryRouterTests {

    /** Failed download attempts are sent to this channel to be routed by {@link ContextConfiguration#failedDownloadRouting( ) } */
    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("failed-channel")
    private MessageChannel failed;

    /** Retry attempts for failed downloads are sent to this channel by {@link ContextConfiguration#failedDownloadRouting( ) }*/
    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("retry-channel")
    private PollableChannel retryChannel;

    /** Failed download attempts which will not be retried, are sent to this channel by {@link ContextConfiguration#failedDownloadRouting( ) }*/
    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("exhausted-channel")
    private PollableChannel exhaustedChannel;

    /**
     * Unit test of {@link ContextConfiguration#failedDownloadRouting( ) } and {@link RetryRouter}.
     */
    @Test
    public void retryRouting() {

        final int limit = 2;

        Message<?> message = failed( 0, limit);

        for ( int attempt = 0 ; attempt <= limit * 2; attempt++ ){

            this.failed.send( message );

            if ( attempt < limit){

                message = this.retryChannel.receive( );
                assertEquals( payload( 0 ) , message.getPayload( ) );
                assertNull(this.exhaustedChannel.receive( 0 ) );

            }else{

                assertEquals( payload( 0 ) , this.exhaustedChannel.receive( ).getPayload( ) );
                assertNull( this.retryChannel.receive( 0 ) );
            }
        }
    }

    private Message<String> failed( int attempt , int limit ) {

        return MessageBuilder
            .withPayload(  payload( attempt ) )
            .setHeader("limit", limit)
            .build();
    }

    private String payload (int attempt){
        return "download attempt "+attempt;
    }


    @Configuration
    @Import({/*ActiveMQAutoConfiguration.class,*/ IntegrationAutoConfiguration.class})
    public static class ContextConfiguration {

        @Bean(name = "failed-channel")
        public MessageChannel failedChannel() {
            return new DirectChannel();
        }

        @Bean(name = "retry-channel")
        public MessageChannel retryChannel() {
            return new QueueChannel();
        }

        @Bean(name = "exhausted-channel")
        public MessageChannel exhaustedChannel() {
            return new QueueChannel();
        }

        /**
         * Decides if a failed download attempt can be retried or not, based upon the number of attempts already made 
         * and the limit to the number of attempts that may be made. Logic is in {@link RetryRouter}.
         * <p>
         * The number of download attempts already made is maintained as a header {@link #attempts}, 
         * and the limit to the number of attempts is another header {@link #retryLimit} which is originally setup upstream as
         * a header by {@link DownloadDispatcher} from retry configuration.
         * <p>
         * Messages for failed download attempts are listened to on channel {@link #failedChannel()}, 
         * are routed to to {@link #retryChannel()} for another attempt or are routed to {@link #exhaustedChannel()} when there no more retries to be made.
         * <p>
         * Refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34693248/how-to-increment-a-message-header for how to increment the attempts header.
         *  
         * @return the {@link IntegrationFlow} defining retry routing message flows
         */
        @Bean
        public IntegrationFlow failedDownloadRouting() {

            return IntegrationFlows.from( "failed-channel" )

                .handle( logMessage ( "failed" ) )

                // adds download attempt counter when it is absent, which is the first iteration only 
                .enrichHeaders( h -> h.header("attempts", new AtomicInteger( 0 ) ) )

                // incremented the download attempt counter for every retry
                .handle( new GenericHandler<Message<String>>( ) {

                    @Override
                    public Object handle( Message<String> payload , Map<String,Object> headers ) {

                        ((AtomicInteger)headers.get( "attempts" )).getAndIncrement();
                        return payload;
                    }})

                .handle( logMessage ( "incremented" ) )

                .route( new RetryRouter( ) )

                .get();
        }

        /**
         * Decides if a failed download attempt can be retried or not, based upon the number of attempts already made 
         * and the limit to the number of attempts that may be made. 
         * <p>
         */
        private static class RetryRouter {

            /**
             * @param attempts current accumulated number of failed download attempts 
             * @param limit maximum number of download attempts
             * @return String channel name into which the message will be routed
             */
            @Router
            public String route(@Header("attempts") AtomicInteger attempts , @Header("limit") Integer limit) {

                if ( attempts.intValue( ) <= limit.intValue( ) ){
                    return "retry-channel";
                }
                return "exhausted-channel";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what you mean by "replace" in this context.

If you mean channels equivalent to those, which are backed by a JMS queue (for persistence reasons only), then use `Jms.channel(cf)` for a `SubscribableChannel` (`DirectChannel` is a `SubscribableChannel`) and `Jms.pollableChannel(cf)` (`QueueChannel` is a `PollableChannel`).

For completeness, a `PublishSubscribeChannel` can be replaced by a `Jms.publishSubscribeChannel(cf)`.

However, if you simply want to send the contents of those channels to Jms for distribution to other systems, it's better to use a `Jms.outboundAdapter()` subscribed to the `DirectChannel` or polling the `QueueChannel`.

JMS-backed channels are not intended for message distribution; they are intended to provide message persistence in order to prevent data loss.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I will mull that over. By "replace" I mean that I want the  flow to be routing messages from an ActiveMQ queue to two ActiveMQ queues.

Comment: In that case, you need a message-driven channel adapter feeding into failed-channel. And the others should also be direct channels sending to outbound channel adapters. Or a single outbound adapter with a destination expression.

Comment: First up, thank you very much: you guys at SI deserve a medal for answering all these inane questions. Your answer above did click with me and I have it running. 

However it has caused a problem with my code: javax.jms.Message does not support AtomicInteger properties so my tests don’t work anymore because the counter doesn’t pass between ActiveMQ and the direct channels, and I can’t see any easy way around this.

Comment: It seems that in enrichHeaders I can create a new header, but I can’t see a way of referencing the current value to increment it. And in the GenericHandler ‘headers’ is immutable so I can’t replace an existing value with its current value + 1. Why is it immutable?

Comment: ltimately what I am trying to do is route failed messages using headers. Ideally as self contained a possible so that senders of failed messages don’t know anything beyond the queue name and setting headers.error. 

Pseudo code

    increment headers.attempts or add if doesn’t exist

    if headers.error is configured (headers[error].config) for retry 
    and header.attempts < headers[error].config.limit

       send message to retry channel with headers.delay containing delay from headers[error].config.delay

    else
        send message to exhausted channel

Comment: Are there any features of SI DSL that can achieve this?

Comment: You should really ask a new question for this; the Stack Overflow admins discourage extended commentary on questions/answers. `.enrichHeaders(c -> c.headerExpression("foo", "headers['foo'] == null ? 1 : headers['foo'] + 1", true))`. The `true` tells the enricher to overwrite the existing header. You could also use a custom JMS Header mapper to map the `AtomicInteger` to an `int` and vice-versa. Generally, for stuff like this, you should ask a new question and reference any related ones.